# how to get facebook friend list using new graph API

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

i am currently develop an app in which i need to add friend's from facebook friend list using new facebook graph API.

This is my code:

```
 _permissions = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         @"read_stream", @"publish_stream", @"offline_access",@"read_friendlists",nil] retain];

[facebook authorize:_permissions];

facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"fbid" andDelegate:self];


[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];
NSMutableDictionary*params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"4",@"uids", @"name", @"fields", nil];
[facebook requestWithMethodName:@"user.getInfo" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"GET" andDelegate:self];
```

but every time it give me error in console
please help me...

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? you are sending 3 requests and I got a little bit confused reading the code.
Make sure your parameters are well defined, you can try pasting your query into your browser to test for results.
What is the error you are getting in the console?

Comment: i am first time using this new graph api. from the sample code of video tutorial on facebook graph api, I write this code for my application. when i run this app i got the error like this ... Failed with error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)

Comment: actually i need only facebook friend's name list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have a code sample that fetches the friends info:

```
        [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" 
                             andParams:[ NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"picture,id,name,link,gender,last_name,first_name",@"fields",nil]
                           andDelegate:self];
```

Remember to:

1. implement the proper delegate methods
2. You must call authorize before fetching the friends information. This way the user will be able to login first.

I hope this helps, cheers

Comment: in the most recent Facebook iOS SDK, "andParams:" must be passed into an NSMutableDictionary instead.

Comment: Should I get friends birthday too ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should swap. Otherwise it's not working.

this is correct way:

```
 facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"fbid" andDelegate:self];
 [facebook authorize:_permissions];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   $friend_list =json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/$uid/friendlists?access_token=$access_token"),true);
   $friend_list_array = $friend_list['data'];
    foreach($friend_list_array as $key=> $value){
$inner_array_name[$value['id']][]=$value['name'];
        }
```